# При использовании одного скрипта в котором генерируется строка в нескольких объектах - строка у всех одинаковая

Tags: unity3d

В скрипте в функции `Start()` выполняется генерация случайной строки.
До запуска значение `itemId` пустое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако после запуска, когда происходит генерация, значения `itemId` заполняется в обоих объектах одинаковое.
[image: И вот что получается при запуске игры]

Вот код генерации:

```
private string generateIID()
    {
        int length = 9;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        System.Random random = new System.Random();
        char letter;
        int number;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            double flt = random.NextDouble();
            int isNumber = random.Next(3);
            int shift = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(25 * flt));
            if(isNumber <= 1)
            {
                letter = Convert.ToChar(shift + 65);
                stringBuilder.Append(letter);
            } else
            {
                number = random.Next(10);
                stringBuilder.Append(number);
            }
            
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Почему так может происходить? Я гуглил, но не смог найти ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, у `new Random` тот же seed. Он зависит от Ticks, если я не ошибаюсь.

Попробуйте `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());`

Но лучше использовать один инстанс Random для всех генераций. Заведите статическое поле:

```
public static Random rand = new Random();
```

Хотя тут возможны проблемы с многопоточностью =)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, объявление инстанса Random как статической переменной помогло